# SELECT information from another query SQL

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to select information from an already run query using SQL. I don't have the rights to create a view which I am aware would solve my problem. I have run the below (obfuscated) query which is throwing a number of errors:

```
SELECT
  distinct(countValue),
  count(countValue)
FROM
(
  SELECT customer_identifier, count(distinct(2nd_customer_identifier)) AS countValue FROM table GROUP BY customer_identifier;
)
GROUP BY
  distinct(countValue)
```

The subquery (below) is attempting to get a count of the unique payees for every customer:

```
SELECT 
    customer_identifier, 
    count(distinct(2nd_customer_identifier)) AS countValue 
FROM table
GROUP BY aid
```

and the main query using that is attempting to get the counted values from the above table and count how many times each one occurs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you logically replace it with the following? This will tell you how many multiple-payer situations you have.

```
SELECT 
    CountValue, 
    count(countValue) TotalRecords
FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT 
        customer_identifier, 
        count(distinct([2nd_customer_identifier])) AS countValue 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY customer_identifier
  ) a
GROUP BY countValue ;
```

Output will tell you something along the lines of:

> There were 25 one-payer accounts
>
> There were 17 two-payer accounts
>
> There were 9 three-payer accounts
>
> Etc.

If that's not what you want, please edit your question to describe the output you are after.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the distinct got rid of the errors